# Technique to freeze all the fields on the form or page of a work item based on certain state in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

On Azure DevOps - I have created a custom work item with custom fields on the page or form of the work item layout. Now as per the process I need the system to freeze all the field updates on certain state Eg: Let's say all the actions on the work item is done then the work item state could be tagged as 'Completed' OR ' Closed' - Now here I need to know if there's any technique to freeze all the fields on the page or form at once. (One way to do it is to set the rules for all the fields BUT if there are over 50 fields on multiple pages of the work item then it may require to set 50 rules which seems to be not the right approach. Kindly suggest!

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this should only be achieved by setting a work item rule. You don't need to set a rule for each field separately, just add multiple actions in a rule to make multiple fields read-only.

[image]